# Variable in shell scripting not printing the whole value

Tags: sh

I want to echo the variable 'param2' value which is retrieved from oracle database and stored in variable. It just reads the 1st four characters and displays it whereas the value is of more than 20 characters. Why doesn't it print the whole value. Can any help to fix it?  Below is my code.

```
        {
        sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
        SET HEADING OFF;
        SET FEEDBACK OFF;
        SET LINESIZE 300;
        select task_seq_no,task_action from dmf_readme_guide_param where task_seq_no = 1;
        ENDOFSQL
        } | while read line
        do
          if [ "$line" ] # Line not NULL
          then
              set $line
              param1="$1"
              param2="$2"
            #  param3="$3"

              # Pass the parameters to a sql plus script
            #  sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDSQL  
            #                      insert into param_testing values($param1);
            #                   commit;

        #ENDSQL
        sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
        SET HEADING OFF;
        SET FEEDBACK OFF;
        SET LINESIZE 300;
        insert into dmf_readme_guide_log(task_seq_no,start_date) values(($param1),sysdate); 
        ENDOFSQL

        echo ($param2)

        sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
        SET HEADING OFF;
        SET FEEDBACK OFF;
        SET LINESIZE 300;
        update dmf_readme_guide_log
        set end_date = sysdate where task_seq_no = ($param1); 
        ENDOFSQL

          fi
        done
```

Comment: Can you give us an excerpt of the output of `select task_seq_no,task_action from dmf_readme_guide_param` ?

Comment: Below is the output of that query:

(TASK_SEQ_NO), (TASK_ACTION)
1, -Get confirmation all applications deployed (including RIB and ORFI)

Comment: and this is what I want to print:  -Get confirmation all applications deployed (including RIB and ORFI)

Answer (score 0):

The problem comes from the parameters assignation with `set $line`. As the output of your SQL query is `1, -Get confirmation all applications`, the `set $line` will affect each space/blank separated values of $line to each parameter indices ($1, $2, $3, etc.).

With the value `1, -Get confirmation all applications` in $line, the `set $line` will then translate into :

```sh
set 1, -Get confirmation all applications
```

Which give :

```sh
$ echo $1 _ $2 _ $3
1, _ -Get _ confirmation
```

As you can see, the $2 parameter receives "-Get" and not "-Get confirmation all applications".

To fully get the second field of the SQL query in $param2, you have to do the parameters assignation with variable substitution and quote :

```sh
#set $line # We have no more use of parameter indices assignation
# We get param1 from the first word of $line
param1="${line%% *}"
# We get param2 from the remaining words of $line
param2="${line#* }"
echo param1=$param1
echo param2=$param2
```

This will output :

```sh
param1=1,
param2=-Get confirmation all applications
```

If you have to deal with a POSIX only shell, you can use parameters shifting to achieve this goal :

```sh
# We use parameter indices assignation to 'split' the output of the SQL query
set $line 
# We get param1 from the first word of $line
param1="$1"
# We get param2 from the remaining parameters by shifting the first
shift
param2="$*"
echo param1=$param1
echo param2=$param2
```

This will output too :

```sh
param1=1,
param2=-Get confirmation all applications
```

With a POSIX shell, take care to escape special character like -,*,$,etc.

Comment: thanks for your kind response. It has fixed this issue but disturbed the assignment of param1 value in insert and update queries. below is the result.

Comment: param2=1
insert into dmf_readme_guide_log(task_seq_no,start_date) values((-Get),sysdate)
                                                                  *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here


param2=confirmation all applications deployed (including RIB and ORFI)
set end_date  = sysdate where task_seq_no = (-Get)
                                              *
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00904: "GET": invalid identifier

Answer (score 0):

I have just fixed it by using another query inside the loop to retrieve that particular task_description based on the task_seq_no returns from the outer loop query and echo this variable only. It worked without disturbing other assignments of param1. below is the code.

```
{
sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
SET HEADING OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET LINESIZE 300;
select task_seq_no
 from dmf_readme_guide_param where task_seq_no = 1;
ENDOFSQL
} | while read line
do
  if [ "$line" ] # Line not NULL
  then
     set $line
      param1="$1"
    #shift
      #param2="$*"
    #  param3="$param2"
     # param3 = $param2
      # Pass the parameters to a sql plus script
    #  sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDSQL  
    #                      insert into param_testing values($param1);
    #           commit;

#ENDSQL
sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
SET HEADING OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET LINESIZE 300;
insert into dmf_readme_guide_log(task_seq_no,start_date) values(($param1),sysdate); 
commit;
ENDOFSQL

RETVAL=`sqlplus -s $UP <<EOF
set echo off term off feed off ver off pages 0
select task_description from dmf_readme_guide_param where task_seq_no = ($param1);
exit 
EOF`
#sh file_1.sh > sh_file_1.log

echo $RETVAL

sqlplus -s $UP <<ENDOFSQL
SET HEADING OFF;
SET FEEDBACK OFF;
SET LINESIZE 300;
update dmf_readme_guide_log
set end_date  = sysdate where task_seq_no = ($param1); 
commit;
ENDOFSQL

  fi    
done
```

Comment: You should then mark your answer as accepted ^^